# osx application red orange green icons

Tags: objective-c, icons

Does anyone know where to get the OSX red orange green icons that appear on the top left of an OSX application?

I want to use these icons to represent different states but do not know where to find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain these from `NSImage`'s `imageNamed:` method passing in the constants `NSImageNameStatusAvailable]`, `NSImageNameStatusPartiallyAvailable]`, `NSImageNameStatusUnavailable]`, `NSImageNameStatusNone` - for green, amber, red and white.

Comment: The images can be previewed under https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the red, yellow, and green buttons in most windows? I can't quote the OSX Human Interface guidelines chapter and verse off the top of my head, but generally it says that you shouldn't reuse Apple defined controls for another (different) function. So you should probably come up with a different control for this.

Comment: Apple use these same dots for the `Network` module within System Preferences. I want to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

```
[myImageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStatusAvailable]]];
[myImageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStatusPartiallyAvailable]]];
[myImageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStatusUnavailable]]];
[myImageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStatusNone]]];
```